# How to change CMake linking order?

Tags: c, cmake

**Context**

When using CMake, I have noticed that the source definition order will influence the linking order.

For example, consider this project with 3 source files.

```
target_sources(my-project.elf PUBLIC
    alpha.c
    beta.c
    gamma.c
)
```

Using `make VERBOSE=1`, we can see linking order is exactly the same has the definition order:

```sh
[100%] Linking C executable my-project.elf
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/my-project.elf.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/local/build_tools/gcc-6.3-arm32-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
[Some linker flags]
CMakeFiles/my-project.elf.dir/alpha.c.obj
CMakeFiles/my-project.elf.dir/beta.c.obj
CMakeFiles/my-project.elf.dir/gamma.c.obj
-o  my-project.elf
```

**Questions**

- Is this a documented feature? (meaning: can I rely on this behaviour?)
- Is there a better way to manage the linker order? (With modern CMake)

**Purpose:**

The embedded systems domain is full of `__weak` function redefinition, functions called from interrupts, inline assembly implementation, etc.

---

**EDIT:**
I realized that linking order is not important.
My problem was related to the way I modelled my dependencies in CMake + the `__weak` functions definition.

Thanks to all.

---

Comment: `Often, projects need a very precise build and linking order to work at runtime.` never happned to me - I do embedded programming for 20y+.

Comment: Maybe I'm jumping to conclusion @P__J__ .
I'm looking for documentation regarding using CMake in the embedded context. Any suggestion ?

Comment: IMO your project idea is bad if it matters.

Comment: `IMO your project idea is bad if it matters.` Tell that to SDK creators hehe.  How would you suggest I improve the project?

Comment: `weak` is unaffected to the linking order of object files passed.

Comment: I did not have any problems with any SDKs. I use NRF, ESP, STM, NXP & TI uCs with many APIs and HALs.

Comment: Only the libraries have to be placed at the end because they scanned only ones for the symbols!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to change CMake linking order?

As far as the linking order of sources of a target is concerned, try reordering the arguments.

As for the linking order of libraries, you can use `target_link_options` with `SHELL:`.

> Is this a documented feature?

No.

> can I rely on this behaviour?

Generally yes, I never seen cmake reordering object files.

> The embedded systems domain is plagued with __weak function redefinition

I would disagree.

> Why link order is important to me

The link order of *object files* is irrelevant - all symbols are loaded at one pass. What is causing problems with `weak` symbols is the linking order of *static libraries*. In modern cmake use `OBJECT` libraries, in older cmake use `--whole-archive` linker flag. When using `whole-archive`, be aware of [LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html#prop_tgt:LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY).

Comment: `The link order of object files is irrelevant - all symbols are loaded at one pass. What is causing problems with weak symbols is the linking order of static libraries` Thanks for your great answer. I edited my question so it better reflects my understanding of the subject. I will look more into `OBJECT`.

Comment: If you have any recommended reading about CMake on an embedded context, I would be interested. Have a great day!

Comment: `you have any recommended reading about CMake on an embedded context` I tend to read existing projects on github, there are so many of them.

Comment: Good idea. Do you have anything specific in mind? I'm always looking for properly structured projects to study.